# Unity WebGL Build

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl, il2cpp

I am trying to release a WebGl build and keep getting the following error messages no matter what I try on the forums.

My build runs fine on any other platform

First error:

> Failed running C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe --convert-to-cpp
>   --compile-cpp --libil2cpp-static --platform="WebGL" --architecture="EmscriptenJavaScript" --configuration="Release" --outputpath="C:\Users\jmassa\Documents\Lidl ENT\Assets /../Temp/StagingArea/Data\Native\build.bc"
>   --cachedirectory="C:\Users\jmassa\Documents\Lidl ENT\Assets..\Library/il2cpp_cache" --compiler-flags="-Oz
>   -DIL2CPP_EXCEPTION_DISABLED=1 " --additional-libraries="C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AIModule_Dynamic.bc"
>   --additional-libraries="C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AnimationModule_Dynamic.bc"
>   --additional-libraries="C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\lib\modules\WebGLSupport_AudioModule_Dynamic.bc"
>   --additional-libraries="C:\Program

Second Error:

> Exception: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe
>   did not run properly! UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunProgram
>   (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args,
>   System.String workingDirectory,
>   UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:130)
>   UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe,
>   System.String args, System.String workingDirectory,
>   UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser,
>   System.Action`1 setupStartInfo) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:73)

Third Error:

> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: Build failed with
>   errors.   at
>   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer
>   (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x001b9] in
>   C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:162
>   at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean
>   askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00050] in
>   C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:83
>   UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

If anyone has any insight it would be much appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ways of fixing build problems: 1.Create a new project, try to build it and see what happens. 2. Open the project that is not building then create an empty scene, try to build it and see what happens. 3. Create a new project, copy the files from the old one one by one and build and check what happens. We don't have your project so we can't really tell what's going on with this general error code.

Comment: I will give this the ol' college try thank you so much, any one else with any input would still be absolutely welcome.

Comment: Trying to build your project on other machines is sometimes helpful. Also you could post your Unity version so others could help further. I had once a very annoying problem and that was WebGL build failed when I had OVR Manager for Oculus, and it was annoying because there were so little hints about it. So anyways it is also possible some of your classes do not support WebGL build.

Comment: @Matthias Yes I am attempting my build on another machine, I had a recurring issue with the build crashing right at the end of it and then I opened up a new blank project and tested WebGl, the same thing happened on an empty file! It must be the same bug I am running Unity 2017.1.0p2 which is the most recent patch. I tested GL on another machine empty and it ran so I zipped up the project and am waiting on the import so that I can attempt to build. I had read that this is a common bug. Thank you for the advice, and any more advice is welcome!

Comment: For those wondering I am using Unity 2017.1.0p2

Answer (score 0):

Build haven't worked for me on Windows 7. Try use Windows 10 latest update

Comment: Please don't write answers that are one line of text and could have been just a simple comment on the user's question.